# Prevent List from being deployed automatically by feature

Tags: deployment, custom-list

I have a list that is deploying with a Site Template.

I have properly set the Definition to deploy with a Site scoped feature, and the Instance to deploy with a Web scoped feature.

All is well, in that when I create the site the list does appear.

The downside is that it also appears at the root site specified in VS2010, which is the site collection.

Will that happen with the WSP deployment as well? IF so how can I stop that, if not, then I assume it's just a VS bug that will go away later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic activation of Sitecollection and Site features is only part of the default VS deployment and will not happen when you deploy the WSP "by hand".

It's not a Bug in VS but a feature which you can turn off on a project basis if it's not appropiate for your project.

- Right click the project in visual studion
- Select Properties
- Select the SharePoint tab
- In Active Deployment Configuration select "No Activation" or build your own Configuration (if you install [CKS: Development Tools](http://cksdev.codeplex.com/) you get a lot extra steps than what's available out of the box)